# Why scipy's splrep shows error on input data?

Tags: python, scipy, spline, bspline

While using scipy's splrep function to fit a cubic B-Spline for the below given data points, the output comes out to be an array of zeros and it says error with input data. I have checked the conditions written in the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html) and input seems sane accordingly.

```
knot = [70.0]
X= [65. ,  67.5, 70. , 72.5]
Y= [70.9277775 , 50.40025663 , 42.45372799 , 57.39316434]
Weight= [0.13514246 , 0.33885943 , 0.87606185 , 0.31531958]
SplineOutput=intp.splrep(X, Y, task=-1, t=knot, full_output=1, w=Weight)
SplineOutput 
>>>((array([65. , 65. , 65. , 65. , 70. , 72.5, 72.5, 72.5, 72.5]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]), 3), 0.0, 10, 'Error on input data')
```

Any help about the source of this error and its cure would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Intuitively I tried fitting the spline without the knot, and it came out good without any error. But does that mean we cannot have consecutive abscissa as Knots or is it a special case due to the fact that it's a near boundary knot? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.splrep.html), under *Notes*

> If provided, knots t must satisfy the Schoenberg-Whitney conditions, i.e., there must be a subset of data points `x[j]` such that `t[j] < x[j] < t[j+k+1]`, for `j=0, 1,...,n-k-2`.

This effectively means that if `k` is 3, which I believe is the default, `n` must be at least 5. In your case, `n` is 4, hence why the error. Either provide an additional entry to `x`, `y` and `w` or decrease `k`. If you opt for the latter, keep the following in mind:

> **k : *int, optional***
>
> The degree of the spline fit. It is recommended to use cubic splines. Even values of k should be avoided especially with small s values. 1 <= k <= 5